# The hyperlink needs two clicks to execute a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a hyperlink and i want to execute a function on the click event of that hyperlink.
The function itself works but the problem is I need two clicks to execute the function.

I tried to google but didnt get anything which works. would be nice if anyone can point out the mistake i am doing...:)

```
$("#btn_logout").click(function () {
             logout(); 

            });
```

and this is the link

```
<a href="#" id="btn_logout">[Log off]</a>
```

Comment: What does the `logout()` function do?

Comment: var logout = function () {
                chat.logout();
                getUsers();
                
            }

Comment: Add logging to the event handler (something like `console.log('logout called');` - this assumes you use Firebug or some other modern debug console). Does it really not execute the first time? It is more likely that the problem is with your own functions.

Comment: alert works in the first click...so it means the problem is in the function..doesnt it?? sorry guys..I should have tried this before...

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

> e.preventDefault();

```
$("#btn_logout").click(function (e) { 
e.preventDefault();
logout(); 
});
```

Comment: no..no error msg. the behaviour is kind of strange for me. If i click once and wait for 5/6 seconds and then click again. it works.

Comment: @kandroid add an `alert` or `console.log` inside the click handler function to see if it fires

Answer (score 0):

[Ignore]
You will also need to stop click from doing the obvious.

```
$("#btn_logout").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}).dblclick(function() {
    logout(); 
});
```

[/Ignore]

I completely got it wrong. Sorry my bad.

I think the solution here can be

```
$("#btn_logout").bind('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    logout();
});
```

I usually bind the event, even if it is supposed to work as .click

Comment: As I read the question the OP wants single click to work. The problem is that logout() is  only executed on dblclick.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btn_logout").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    logout();
});​
```